# Django SearchVector

Tags: python, django, postgresql, search

Django SearchVector is giving ok results in command line but it is not working on my localhost:8000. Here's how I put it.

```
def post_search(request):

     form = SearchForm()
     query = None
     results = []

     if 'query' in request.GET:
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            query= form.cleaned_data['query']
            results = Post.objects.annotate(search=SearchVector('title', 'body', 
           'slug')).filter(search='query')

     context = {
        'form' : form,
        'query' : query,
        'results' : results }

     return render(request, 'blog/search.html', context)
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? If so please add this to make it easier.

Comment: No. That's the scary part !!

Comment: @AbdullahAtif: that is not scary: it is just searching for the *string* `query`, so regardless what you enter; the results will be the result of searching for `query`.

Comment: By the way thanks for bothering. I already have it cleared. Stuck bcz my first time with search.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `query`, not the `'query'` string:

```
def post_search(request):
    form = SearchForm()
    query = None
    results = []
    
    if 'query' in request.GET:
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            query = form.cleaned_data['query']
            results = Post.objects.annotate(
                search=SearchVector('title', 'body', 'slug')
            ).filter(search=query)
            # query variable ↑

    context = {
        'form' : form,
        'query' : query,
        'results' : results
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/search.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried single filter quotes? Try it in this way `filter(search=query)`.